# regex matching a pattern but only replacing a part of the match in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to understand backreferences, and I think a simple example would help me.

Say I have the string "$1 per kayak + 40k + $10 per kite sold" and want it to be "$1 per kayak + 40000 + $10 per kite sold"

How can I do this in REGEX in R?  I clearly don't just want to replace "k" with "000".  I also can't just use `sub()` because the match might not be the first occurrence in the string.

Comment: Ok, so what are the rules? `k` when preceded with a digit and followed with a word boundary should be replaced?

Comment: Yes, basically track numbers in the thousands represented using "k".

Comment: The `\1` does not multiply anything, it only puts back into the result the substring captured with the first `(...)`.

Comment: It's all starting to make sense!!  Thank you so much

Comment: But that means your question is unclear. What do you need exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Adding `ignore.case` based on @WiktorStribiżew 's comment

```
string  = "$1 per kayak + 40k + $10 per kite sold"
gsub("(\\b\\d+)k\\b", "\\1000", string,  ignore.case=TRUE)
[1] "$1 per kayak + 40000 + $10 per kite sold"
```

Comment: If only stackexchange had an answer for EVERY regex question I had. I guess that would be regexchange...

Comment: Why not a simpler `gsub("(\\d)k\\b", "\\1000", string)`? Besides, `ignore.case=TRUE` would be also helpful.

Comment: For this string, they would work the same, I was protecting against a string like "His license number is G8K-4D2".  But you are right that `ignore.case=TRUE` would be helpful.  I will add it to the solution.

Comment: You could imagine other generalizations.  What if there was a blank space between 40 and k?

Comment: Can you please explain how the "\\1000" backreference is working?  Why the "\\" and how does it know to multiply by 1,000 and not replace with or add 1,000?

Comment: @PabloBoswell The back-reference is \\1 the first parenthesized expression.   Really, the expression we want to construct is \1  but to get that string you need to escape the backslash so you get two backslashes. The 000 is just literal; follow whatever number was captured in the back-reference by three zeros.